# Iterate over all possible combinations of input variables in mathematica

Tags: function, loops, iteration, wolfram-mathematica, combinations

I have a self-defined function in Mathematica, which has the following syntax:

```
outputval = myfunc[r, sigma, S, K, T, lambda, eta1, eta2, p]
```

When the function is called as above with numeric input values, it outputs a single output value.

For each input variable I have 5 different values. I want to input all combinations of all 5 values of the 9 input variables in my function and export a CSV file containing the 9 input values and their respective output value in the 10th column.

I am very new to Mathematica and I have no clue how to do so. Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example will illustrate how to get what you want:

```
xvals = {1, 2}
yvals = {3, 4}
{Sequence @@ #, f @@ #} & /@ Tuples[{xvals, yvals}]
```

Warning: 5^9==1953125.  So you may with to use a `Do` loop and write directly to file instead of creating these lists.  To illustrate:

```
fmt = StringTemplate["``,``,``"];
Do[Print[fmt[x, y, f[x, y]]], {x, xvals}, {y, yvals}]
```

You'll want to replace `Print` with `WriteLine`.